# .htaccess allow hotlinking of images with parameter (?something)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, hotlinking

I have code in my .htaccess file to prevent hot-linking of images on my site.
What I need is to make it allow hot-linking of images it they have some parameter at the end of URL, for example:

This image should be blocked:

```
https://my-site.com/my-images/some-image-file-name.jpg
```

BUT, ALLOW hot-linking if that same image have parameter at the end, for example:

```
https://my-site.com/my-images/some-image-file-name.jpg?allow_hot_linking
```

WHY I NEED SOMETHING LIKE THIS?
For example, if image is sent inside html email, it will not be displayed, but if I could make some .htaccess rule which would allow hot-linking of images with parameter I will simply put that parameter at the end of img source tag of image while making html email and it will appear when email is opened.

This is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?my-site.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?nnn.nnn.nn.nnn [NC]
##Allow search engines
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Googlebot-Image [NC]
.
.
.
##Allow blank referrers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
## Redirect to hotlink image
RewriteRule ^my-images/(.*).(jpeg|jpg|bmp)$ https://my-site.com/no-hotlinking.html [NC,R,L]
## End - prevent image hotlinking
```

Comment: did you try 
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ! allow_hot_linking 
  i'm not sure of syntax

Comment: Yes, that's it. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !allow_hot_linking [NC]

Comment: I already tried it (I probably made tiny syntax mistake), but you bring me to right road again. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think it can be a conflict between your  "Allow blank referrers"  Rule and your "Allow my site" Rule
It can't be blank *and* my-site.com , you may need to use the [S]kip Flag or [OR]

Comment: Just add a new condition: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^allow_hot_linking$ [NC]`  in your rule.

Answer (score 0):

Love this solution, exactly what I was looking for to allow links from emails but not from blank referrers.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ahl$ [NC]
```

Works a dream.